# GCP : Cannot release unused external IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a static, external ip address named nat-auto-ip-5498886-1-xxx (xxx actually a long number) that cannot be released.

When I select this IP address and click release I get the following response :

> The deletion of the address failed. Error: Request contains an invalid
>   argument.

I really want to delete this external ip address since it is not used and will be billed.

Comment: It might be super useful if you capture the steps you are following to delete it and a screen shot of the error message in context.

Comment: I am not sure how are you trying to delete it (console or command line) 
Can you try with:
gcloud compute addresses delete nat-auto-ip-5498886-1-xxx

Comment: @grimmjow_sms using gcloud CLI reveals a more useful error : ERROR: (gcloud.compute.addresses.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - NAT_AUTO addresses cannot be deleted. Delete the associated NAT config instead.
I think I will check around NAT if something can be deleted.

Comment: go to: Networking > Network Services > Cloud Nat
And check if you have something setup there, if so and you don't need it, delete it. Then run the delete command again

Answer (score 0):

That external IP is being used with a Cloud NAT. You need to remove the Cloud NAT first before you can release that IP